# travis-ci fails on typings install

Tags: npm, travis-ci, npm-install

I'm trying to get travis-ci going on my angular2 project, which uses npm to install typings, but travis-ci fails on typings install.

**error**

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/travis/build/borysn/spring-boot-angular2/src/main/web/node/node-v6.2.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/travis/build/borysn/spring-boot-angular2/src/main/web/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! spring-boot-angular2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the spring-boot-angular2@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT postinstall script 'typings install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the spring-boot-angular2 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs spring-boot-angular2
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls spring-boot-angular2
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/travis/build/borysn/spring-boot-angular2/src/main/web/npm-debug.log
:npmInstall FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were changes in typings 1.0 that I missed, make sure to read through [updating from 0.x to 1.0](https://github.com/typings/typings#updating-from-0x-to-10)

Comment: Can you share your `.travis.yml` file? I have the same problem

Comment: @aral [.travis-ci.yml](https://github.com/borysn/spring-boot-angular2/blob/master/.travis.yml) and [typings.json](https://github.com/borysn/spring-boot-angular2/blob/master/src/main/web/typings.json) valid for typings 1.0